# Переместить объект в окне программно WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли переместить объект программно, не применяя ThicknessAnimation и подобные классы?

> Задача такая - в окне есть Image и Button. Нажатие на Button изменяет положение Image.

Comment: поменять координаты не?

Comment: Не, это тебе не Win Form, тут Location нэма)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблем особенных нет.

Если вам нужно руководить координатами, поместите объект в `Canvas`, и управляйте координатами при помощи `Canvas.SetLeft` и `Canvas.SetTop`.

```
<Button Click="OnButtonClicked"/>
<Canvas>
    <Image Name="MoveTarget" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" ... />
</Canvas>
```

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(MoveTarget, 100);
    Canvas.SetTop(MoveTarget, 100);
}
```

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но у меня возник вопрос: а если этот способ применять совместно с ThicknessAnimation? Дополнительно ввести кнопку, которая будет перемещать Image в другое место , но с помощью ThicknessAnimation. Короче говоря, они не "погрызутся?"

Comment: @Marchosias: А к какому свойству вы применяете `ThicknessAnimation`? Возможно, вы делаете что-то не так, а на самом деле надо что-то из этого: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753933(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Мне нужно после анимации вернуть объект в исходное положение. Пытался делать через задание свойства `Img.Margin = new Thickness {300,100,0,0}` - реакции нет

Comment: @Marchosias: Не-не, всё не так просто. Вам стоит разобраться, как работает `DependencyProperty`. Если кратко, то анимация накладывается «поверх» текущего значения, и поэтому, чтобы отменить анимацию, вам таки надо её отменить саму, а не менять исходное значение. (У анимации должно быть свойство, которое говорит о том, возвращаться или нет в исходное состояние после окончания работы, посмотрите!)

Comment: @Marchosias: Маргин — не самая лучшая для этого вещь. Лучше и правда поместите картинку в Canvas и управляйте координатами прямо.